# Slot machine distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

A slot machine owner advertises at a stake of €1 per game. With a probability of 0.25 we we win €4 and with a probability of 0.75 we get nothing back. Now I am looking for the distribution of how long you have to play until you win. But I can't find the start. Thanks for your help!

Comment: [Geometric distribution.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) (Beware the two variants: one includes the winning game in the count of "how long you have to play," while the other does not.)

Comment: Okay so I guess in my case I have to take this variant: $\operatorname{P}(X=n)= p(1-p)^{n-1}= pq^{n-1} \quad (n=1,2, \dotsc)$, right?

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved using a very simple Markov Chain, with the starting state $\emptyset$, and probability of $p_{\emptyset, 1} = 0.25$. Now, using this fact, you can construct and solve a very simple set of recurrent equations to get the solution. Keep in mind the actual value of win has nothing to do with probabilities of winning.

EDIT:

The main recurrent equation is
$$
h_{\emptyset, 1} = 0.75 h_{\emptyset, 1}  + 0.25 h_{1, 1} \\
h_{1,1}=1
$$

Comment: Thanks for you answer. We hadn't the Markov Chain until now, so I guess it will be hard to use it.

Comment: Pls see the edit

Comment: Wow okay, I am sorry but my research about the Markov Chain leads me to formula that I am not able to handle

Comment: Apologies, used the wrong subscript. See the edit.